# How to do a Model inside another Model to save a information

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, postgresql, sqlite

I am developing something and I have difficulty with a part of the Model, I registered a client and within this client, I would like to register his credit and debit information.

He will borrow money and I need to register it, inside the client, so I need to enter the information of how much money he acquired with us and register manually, and every time he makes a payment, I need to register inside him too to see how much remains to be paid.

I have no idea how to do this, I need to save an information inside another information and go to feed it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can re-use this example from the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/instances/:

```py
class BookManager(models.Manager):
    def create_book(self, title):
        book = self.create(title=title)
        # do something with the book
        return book

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    objects = BookManager()

book = Book.objects.create_book("Pride and Prejudice")
```

For you, the class `Client` should have a field containing a class `CreditInformation` or something like this

Comment: Hi Miionu, i created the scope https://i.imgur.com/7YE03gA.png to verify what i need exactly. Im in the picture is inside the client and need to insert the information in "Descrição (Description)" and click in "Incluir (Add)". That information will be saved as a "client/transition history". It will create a History of Transition of client, inside the Model Client.